# Matlab's VAR[X] coefficient constraints for vector time series

Tags: matlab, time-series

Matlab's VARMAX model allows the user to set flags that determine whether individual linear coefficients are to be estimated.  In particular, vgxset accepts an ARsolve parameter containing flags that determine whether individual time series lag coefficients are estimated.  The fact that there are individual scalar flags for each scalar lag term implies each coefficient can be activated independently.

I have 3 questions concerning this flexible feature.

(1) Does turning off a flag essentially mean that the corresponding coefficient is zero?

(2) Where is the documentation of which switch is for which coefficient?  That is, for a given lag, if I wanted to turn on the coefficient for the dependence of series i on series j, would I turn on flag (i,j) or (j,i)?

(3) Since AR0solve is ignored, does that mean that there is no contemporaneous dependence between time series?

I have posted this to:

- [Matlab's VAR[X] coefficient constraints for vector time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518736/matlabs-varx-coefficient-constraints-for-vector-time-series)
- http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/5AIeQYoqeWg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Friday, May 29, 2015 at 2:05:06 PM UTC-4, Rick wrote:

> (1) No, not necessarily. Turning off a flag (i.e., setting a 
>   particular element of an input "solve" flag to logical FALSE) holds 
>   the corresponding parameter value fixed throughout the estimation.
>
> For example, if, say, the 3rd element of the "asolve"  parameter is 
>   FALSE (logical 0) and the 3rd element of the corresponding value 
>   parameter "a" is such that a(3) = 0, then the estimation will 
>   effectively exclude that coefficient from the model.
>
> The important thing is that the parameter is held fixed at whatever 
>   you specify. Of course, to hold a coefficient fixed you also need to 
>   indicate the its value, and so the "asolve" and "a" parameters must 
>   both be set.
>
> These values do not necessarily need to be zero, although zeros 
>   (i.e., exclusion constraints) are very common.
>
> (2) The best I have found is the reference page for "vgxset" 
>   function. There might be specific examples in the documentation, but 
>   the reference page is the place I'd start.
>
> As for your 2nd sentence, I think you are over-thinking the storage. 
>   There is a 1-to1 correspondence between the solve parameter and its 
>   paired value.
>
> I suggest you simply write out a  2-D VAR model and contrive a 
>   simple experiment. The model, and placement of coefficients and 
>   corresponding TRUEs/FALSEs, conforms to the linear algebra of the 
>   equation.
>
> (3) Yes, at least from the perspective of model estimation.
>
> That is, "vgxvarx" will not estimate "structural" VAR models, and so 
>   the corresponding "AR0" structural coefficient is not estimated. You 
>   can specify a non-identity AR0 coefficient, in which case the 
>   estimation simply fits the VAR model to the modified series A0*y(t). 
>   So, in this case you can effect contemporaneous dependence between 
>   the series, but you cannot estimate it.

On Friday, May 29, 2015 at 2:40:28 PM UTC-4, paul.d...@gmail.com 
wrote:

> I just want to check a specific detail about answer#2.  I am 
>   thinking of the matrix representation of the equations when I mull 
>   over the vgxset parameters.  Are the boolean flags for solving the 
>   coefficients suppose to form a symmetric matrix?  I was more 
>   interested in the assymetric case were, e.g., for a given lag, 
>   series i depends on series j according to some coefficient that is 
>   different from the dependence of series j on series i.  If that 
>   constraint is not necessary, and the flags occupy exactly the same 
>   positions as the coefficients themselves, I think I can run with 
>   that.

On Saturday, May 30, 2015 at 6:41:04 AM UTC-4, Rick wrote:

> Paul,  no, the Boolean flags need not form a symmetric matrix. Best, Rick

So getting the meaning of the row and column of the flag becomes important, and the meaning of the row and column comes from the matrix for the coefficient to which the flag corresponds.  Based on my understanding of the vector setup, the row represents the dependent series while the column represents the predictor series.